# Incompatible Arguments Exception Java

Tags: java, exception

Can anyone explain to me what this exception does? and how I would use it in the Add function?

```
public class IncompatibleArgumentsException extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4578095021520647821L;

    public IncompatibleArgumentsException() {
        super();
    }

    public IncompatibleArgumentsException(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public IncompatibleArgumentsException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

    public IncompatibleArgumentsException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }
}
```

Add function header:

```
int[][] add(int[][] a, int[][] b) throws IncompatibleArgumentsException;
```

Comment: what do you mean, what does it do? It's an exception... it does the same like every other exception in java

Comment: Is this a homework question? Because if you know the basics of Java, and the why and how of exceptions (which is Java basics) you already know the answer to this question...

Comment: Exceptions don't do anything, per se. *Throwing* an exception does something, but that's the throwing, not the exception.

Comment: Java has no IncompatibleArgumentsException defined in the JDK afaik. It is most probably some implementation that someone designed. In any case, the throws statement is kind of not doing anything because it is a runtime exception. But to actually answer the question, it could possibly mean that for example a's length is not 3 (in case it expects to recieve an array with 3 sub arrays.)

Answer (score 0):

It fills out a stack trace for the method add when the parameters passed are not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

The exception functions identically to [`RuntimeException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/RuntimeException.html), you create a new instance (with an optional message and/or cause) and throw it. The only difference is that you can do this:

```
try {
    x.add(a, b);
} catch (IncompatibleArgumentsException e) {
    // handle incompatible arguments here
}
```

If you were throwing and catching `RuntimeException` instead, your catch block would end up running on `NullPointerException` or `IndexOutOfBoundsException` or any other type of `RuntimeException`. This way, you can have your method throw `IncompatibleArgumentsException` when it determines the arguments are incompatible, and you can have a catch block that handles only that specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

progress soft !!
just throw the exception in an if else statement using the conditions u have on the functions

Comment: i promise you I will :)